# Macbook boots up to grey 'prohibited' symbol

Tags: macbook-pro, hard-drive, startup

I'm having an issue with my '09 13" Macbook Pro. When I boot it up, it seems to be booting normally until about thirty seconds in, when the Apple symbol is replaced with a kind of 'no-smoking' symbol, without the cigarette in the middle.

I've removed the drive one and put it in an external holder, and repaired it using Disk Utility on my Macbook Air. It found some things, and said it repaired them. I then put the drive into my Macbook Pro again, and it booted *once* to only one of my partitions. It acted very laggy and slow, and eventually I had to force kill it with the power button. Now it does the same thing.

I'm in the process of removing the hard drive to try to repair it again, but I wanted to know if anyone here has any ideas on what this could be. Is it the machine itself somehow?

I see this:

[image]

Comment: Sounds like your hard drive is dead… :-(

Comment: But it sounds perfect, @Asmus, and I can mount it on another machine just fine.

Comment: Have you tried booting on the other machine?

Comment: Right now I'm trying to boot on the 'problematic' machine itself, via USB, @Anno

Comment: @shub Exactly the same.

Comment: @Undo Dead hard drives don't alway produce a bad noise; in your case your Mac seems to be unable to find the boot system, meaning there could be corrupt sectors in an area where the system files reside, while the drive itself is perfectly mountable. Another explanation (while not as likely) are defect hard drive connector cables or even the main board. Try booting your Mac from a different (usb) drive or DVD if you have.

Comment: I can boot from the hard drive fine when I remove it and boot from an attached USB enclosure, @Asmus. Intriguing...

Comment: @Undo Well, the drive sectors that are used for things like swapping memory are chosen randomly at boot, as far as I know, so it could be just coincidence if you run into these errors at boot or later. Usually I'd go on with a backup on a new drive, but if I see it correctly, you've got a MacBook **Air** (says *Pro* in the first sentence), so I see that it wouldn't be easy to just buy a replacement drive… If you have a perfect backup, you could erase the hard drive with zeroes and see if it manages to finish. If it does, then it's your cables or (worse) logic board.

Comment: I have a MacBook *Pro*

Comment: I always try repairing it twice in a row. If it fixes stuff then finds more problems the second time, you know something serious is wrong.

Comment: If you can back up your data and want to wipe it, make sure you repartition the entire drive, replacing the old partition scheme, rather than simply reformatting your boot partition.

Comment: That also means invalid instruction, perhaps something wasn't installed right, or something like that?

Answer (score 0):

There are times when Apple's 'Disk Utility' software isn't as thorough at repairing problems that other applications may be.
I've had 'Disk Utility' tell me that drives are fine, but it is not until after running a program like 'Disk Warrior' (that replaces the Directory structure), that the hard drive feels 'normal' again.
This isn't to plug any particular software, but to let you know that 'Disk Utility' isn't the be all, end all of determining if a hard drive is 'good'.

Given your description of the problem, I'd be inclined to make sure I had a backup. If not, purchase a new hard drive, and get all the data off of the old one as quick as possible. (I agree with @Asmus that it appears that you are about to lose a hard drive).

On the other hand, you may just need to have the mac reinstall the OS, and fix things that way. Either way - make sure you have a solid backup right away.

Good luck.